# Non-Lipschitz homeomorphism from compact metric space to itself

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Is it possible to find a compact metric space $(X,d)$ with more than one point and a homeomorphism $\varphi:(X,\tau) \to (X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ is the topology induced by $d$ such that $$(\forall N\in \mathbb{N})(\exists x, y\in X): x\neq y \text{ and }  d(f(x),f(y)) \geq N\cdot d(x,y)?$$

Comment: Sure. $\:$ Let $X$ be non-empty, and let $y$ equal $x$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Oh I see your point. I have amended the question

Comment: You could've just made the inequality strict. $\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X=[0,1]$ with the usual metric, $\phi(x)=\sqrt x$.